# How to get and assign variables from tensorflow premade estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement DQN by DNNClassifier in tensorflow r1.5. Now I need to implement the variable exchange between target net and evaluation net but I can find the way neither to retrieve variables from `tf.Estimator` nor to assign value to another Estimator.

I know I can get the values by `tf.estimator.get_variable_value(name)` but there isn't a function to assign the values. I think the only way to assign values to variables is `tf.assign`. However, this function require the reference to Variable Tensor which may be gotten by `tf.trainable_variables` or `tf.Graph.get_collection` if you manually build the graph.

I've tried calling `tf.trainable_variables` after `estimator.train` but got an empty list. Here is my code (the data is just some random value):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

x = {"x": [1, 13, 26, 37, 47, 67, 49]}
y = [1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1]  

my_feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="x")]

def my_input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)) 
    return dataset.shuffle(100).repeat().batch(3).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[10],
        n_classes=2)

classifier.train(input_fn=my_input_fn, steps=500)

print(tf.trainable_variables()
```

Is there a way to do such work?